# Интерактивная карта

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

```
<area href="#" title="Белгородская область" alt="" shape="poly" coords="38,305,38,310,42,314,46,315,47,318,48,322,48,326,49,328,54,323,55,316,54,312,51,309,47,308,41,304">
```

Подскажите как ведеться расчет coords. Заранее буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас должно быть заранее подготовлено изображение карты, с предварительно расчерченными границами. В данном случае на картинке вы выделяете [Белгородскую область](http://bayguzin.ru/demo/maps/) с координатами `coords="38,305,38,310,42,314,..`.

Значение координат многоугольника `shape="rect"` определяется по формуле `coords="x1,y1,x2,y2.."`, значит у вас это будет `coords="38,305,38,310.."`. Т.е. это смещение каждой точки в многоугольнике по оси `x` и `y` в пикселях. Координаты перечисляются по часовой стрелке.

Можете почитать [небольшую статью](http://www.webuchebnik.ru/samouchitel_html/klient_map_2.php).

Comment: У меня карта уже есть - как мне точно получить координаты?

Comment: В статье же все написано! Если кустарным методом, то, значит, открываешь фотошоп, наводишь мышкой на каждый угол и вперед, записывать координаты x и y, которые видишь в панели INFO, через запятую по часовой стрелке.)

Answer (score 0):

Набор координат определяется формой (горячей областью), задается атрибутом **shape**.

У shape есть четыре значения:
***rect*** - область в виде прямоугольника.
***circle*** - область в виде окружности
***poly*** – область в виде полигона (многоугольника)
***default*** – вся имеющаяся область.

Для прямоугольного выделения области (***rect***) задаются 4ре координата:
1 – расстояние в пикселях слева (указываем, сколько нужно отступить слева)
2 – расстояние в пикселях сверху (указываем, сколько нужно отступить сверху)
3 – расстояние в пикселях дальнего, верхнего угла (фактически, указываем ширину нашей прямоугольной области)
4 - расстояние в пикселях дальнего, нижнего угла (фактически, указываем высоту нашей прямоугольной области)

Для выделения области в виде окружности (***circle***) задаются 3ри координата:
1 – расстояние в пикселях слева (указываем, сколько нужно отступить слева)
2 – расстояние в пикселях сверху (указываем, сколько нужно отступить сверху)
3 – радиус нашей области.

**Примечание!** Координаты чередуются по парам: первое число отвечает за расстояние влево, второе за расстояние сверху (X,Y, X2,Y2, X3,Y3…).

Для выделения области в виде полигона (***poly***) задаются “сколько угодно” координата:

К примеру, прямоугольник:

- указываем верхнюю точку нашего прямоугольника:
  1(X) – расстояние в пикселях слева (указываем, сколько нужно отступить слева)
  2(Y) – расстояние в пикселях сверху (указываем, сколько нужно отступить сверху)
- указываем нижнюю, левую точку нашего прямоугольника:
  3(X1) – расстояние в пикселях слева (указываем, сколько нужно отступить слева)
  4(Y1) – расстояние в пикселях сверху (указываем, сколько нужно отступить сверху)
- указываем нижнюю, правую точку нашего прямоугольника:
  5(X2) – расстояние в пикселях слева (указываем, сколько нужно отступить слева)
  6(Y2) – расстояние в пикселях сверху (указываем, сколько нужно отступить сверху)

**Примечание!** Представьте, что от верхней (первой) точки (***1*** и ***2***), ведутся линии к тем точкам, что вы указываете после: ***3*** и ***4***, ***5*** и ***6***,...

Также, можете воспользоваться специальными генераторами координат:
http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/